# CATBoost and GridSearch

Tags: python, grid-search, catboost, boosting

```
model.fit(train_data, y=label_data, eval_set=eval_dataset)
eval_dataset = Pool(val_data, val_labels)
model = CatBoostClassifier(depth=8 or 10, iterations=10, task_type="GPU", devices='0-2', eval_metric='Accuracy', boosting_type="Ordered", bagging_temperature=0, use_best_model=True)
```

When I run the code above (in 2 separate runs / depth set to 8 or 10) I get the following results:

Depth 10: 0.6864865
Depth 8:   0.6756757

I would like to setup and run GridSearch in a way - so it runs exactly the same combinations and produces the exact same results - as when I run the code manually.

GridSearch code:

```
model = CatBoostClassifier(iterations=10, task_type="GPU", devices='0-2', eval_metric='Accuracy', boosting_type="Ordered", depth=10, bagging_temperature=0, use_best_model=True)

grid = {'depth': [8,10]}
grid_search_result = GridSearchCV(model, grid, cv=2)
results = grid_search_result.fit(train_data, y=label_data, eval_set=eval_dataset)
```

Issues:

1. I would like the GridSearch to use my "eval_set" to compare/validate all the different runs (like when run manually) - But it uses something else which I don't understand what is and it doesn't seems to look at "eval_set" at all?
2. It produces not only 2 results - but depending on the "cv" (The cross-validation splitting strategy.) param it run 3,5,7,9 or 11 runs? I don't want that.
3. I tried to go through the entire "results" object via the debugger - but I simply can't find the validation "Accuracy" scores for the best or all the other runs. I can find a lot of other values - but none of them matches what I'm looking for. The numbers don't match the numbers the "eval_set" dataset produces?

I solved my issue by implementing my own simple GridSearch (In case it can help/ inspire others :-) ): Please let my know if you have any comments to the code :-)

```
import pandas as pd
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier, Pool
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import csv
from datetime import datetime

# Initialize data

train_data = pd.read_csv('./train_x.csv')
label_data = pd.read_csv('./labels_train_x.csv')
val_data = pd.read_csv('./val_x.csv')
val_labels = pd.read_csv('./labels_val_x.csv')

eval_dataset = Pool(val_data, val_labels)

ite = [1000,2000]
depth = [6,7,8,9,10]
max_bin = [None,32,46,100,254]
l2_leaf_reg = [None,2,10,20,30]
bagging_temperature = [None,0,0.5,1]
random_strength = [None,1,5,10]
total_runs = len(ite) * len(depth) * len(max_bin) * len(l2_leaf_reg) * len(bagging_temperature) * len(random_strength)

print('Total runs: ' + str(total_runs))

counter = 0

file_name = './Results/Catboost_' + str(datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S")) + '.csv'

row = ['Validation Accuray','Logloss','Iterations', 'Depth', 'Max_bin', 'L2_leaf_reg', 'Bagging_temperature', 'Random_strength']
with open(file_name, 'a') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerow(row)
csvFile.close()

for a in ite:
    for b in depth:
        for c in max_bin:
            for d in l2_leaf_reg:
                for e in bagging_temperature:
                    for f in random_strength:
                        model = CatBoostClassifier(task_type="GPU", devices='0-2', eval_metric='Accuracy', boosting_type="Ordered", use_best_model=True,
                        iterations=a, depth=b, max_bin=c, l2_leaf_reg=d, bagging_temperature=e, random_strength=f)
                        counter += 1
                        print('Run # ' + str(counter) + '/' + str(total_runs))
                        result = model.fit(train_data, y=label_data, eval_set=eval_dataset, verbose=1)

                        accuracy = float(result.best_score_['validation']['Accuracy'])
                        logLoss = result.best_score_['validation']['Logloss']

                        row = [ accuracy, logLoss,
                                ('Auto' if a == None else a),
                                ('Auto' if b == None else b),
                                ('Auto' if c == None else c),
                                ('Auto' if d == None else d),
                                ('Auto' if e == None else e),
                                ('Auto' if f == None else f)]

                        with open(file_name, 'a') as csvFile:
                            writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
                            writer.writerow(row)
                        csvFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The eval set in Catboost is acting as a holdout set.

In GridSearchCV the cv is performed on your train_data.

One solution would be to merge your train_data and eval_dataset and pass the index of train and eval in GridSearchCV. Try to yield both sets of index in the **cv** param. Then you will have just one split and Accuracy numbers that will give you the same results.

Comment: Could you please provide a code example as well - for better understanding?